# How do I deploy a Truffle Dapp on webserver?

Tags: dapps

how do I deploy a in Truffle built, working and migrated Dapp to a webserver so that I could send the link to friends to interact with my smart contract via MetaMask e.g.?

Answer (score 1):

Assumed you tested everything on a local webserver, e.g. Apache (in Linux, you can quickly start a tdevelopment instance with `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080` and opening `localhost:8080`in browser. If that works, you can just upload everything on a real webserver.

If you use the truffle webpack boilerplate (`truffle unbox webpack`) just do `npm run build` after you migrated the contracts, and upload the contents of the build folder to a webserver.